# Sending path through Java NiO

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I am programming a server and a client, the client will send a file to the server, however, I need to send the file name together, so that the server recognizes and write the file with the name sent by the client. Currently it does not send the file name, so I must inform the server of the file name and its path where it will be saved.
Is it possible to send the file name and path that will be saved to the file?
And if it is possible, what code snippet should I use to be able to point out such information?
If Anyone can help me, I really appreciate it.

client side

```
public class FileSenderClient {
    private void sendFile(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\SIS\\database.FDB");\\ path to file 
        FileChannel inChannel = FileChannel.open(path);

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        while (inChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
            buffer.flip();
            socketChannel.write(buffer);
            buffer.clear();
        }
        socketChannel.close();
    }
    private SocketChannel CreateChannel() throws IOException {

        SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(true);
        SocketAddress sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9000);
        socketChannel.connect(sockAddr);
        return socketChannel;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileSenderClient client = new FileSenderClient();
        SocketChannel socketChannel = client.CreateChannel();
        client.sendFile(socketChannel);
    }
}
```

server side

```
public class FileReceiver {

        private void readFileFromSocketChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws IOException {

        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Data\\database.FDB"); - here  i need to receive
                                                           the name from the class FileSenderClient
        FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(path,
                EnumSet.of(StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                        StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING,
                        StandardOpenOption.WRITE)
                );
        //Allocate a ByteBuffer
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        while (socketChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
            buffer.flip();
            fileChannel.write(buffer);
            buffer.clear();
        }
        fileChannel.close();
        System.out.println("Receving file successfully!");
        socketChannel.close();
    }

    private SocketChannel createServerSocketChannel() throws IOException {
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocket = null;
        SocketChannel client = null;
        serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocket.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(9000));
        client = serverSocket.accept();

        System.out.println("connection established .." + client.getRemoteAddress());
        return client;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReceiver server = new FileReceiver();
        SocketChannel socketChannel = server.createServerSocketChannel();
        server.readFileFromSocketChannel(socketChannel);

    }


}
```

Comment: There are dozens of ways to do this. However, they all require you to have a good grip on "Java Sockets". Judging from the way you posed your question, most of this code is copied and pasted from somewhere else, making it hard for you to understand the basic mechanism on which your server works.